# useful set of cookbook examples of perl xml::libxml dom parser for (x)html?

Tags: xml, html, perl, xhtml, xml-libxml

the authors of some simpler perl dom parsers for xml seem to discourage their use for mixed content in favor of XML::LibXML.  so I am now beginning to learn XML::LibXML and am looking for cookbook examples of common use.  think reading (x)html documents from the web and doing operations with it.  (the perl cookbook 2nd edition is now 10 years old, and its coverage here is relatively weak.)  I figured out that I want to start with:

```
use XML::LibXML;
my $dom = XML::LibXML->load_xml( location => "fame-1-1.html", recover => 2 );
## recover=>2 is needed to allow valid html entities
```

good recipe examples that starters could use would include

1. converting a $dom into a perl data structure.  Data::Dumper($dom) did not get me anything particularly interesting.  of course, I want to convert both ways: from and to.
2. pretty printing the output, perhaps with some control.
3. sanitizing html to xhtml.
4. doing transformations with logic.  (there are nice examples of doing things with individual dom elements, but I am thinking more generalizable.)  for example, how do I operate on two consecutive dom elements?  I have a XAB.  I want to add a "class" or "style" to the sup if thus consecutive (e.g., style="width:0").
5. breaking out all classes and styles into a minimal template style sheet.
6. other "cool" and "simple" uses for XML::LibXML.
7. (left for subsequent editing of the question in response to useful recipes)  suggestions:

   (a) enumerate with an incrementing id each <li> inside a <ul> (e.g., <li id="1"> ... <li id="2"> ...).  could be done with multiple elements

   (b) iterating over multiple tags (e.g., print out in sequence of occurrence all li, dl and dt)

samples appreciated.

/iaw

Comment: Note that HTML != XML. Use a specialized HTML parser that is aware of HTML5 and certain other quirks instead.

Comment: yes, I was thinking of the serialized version xhtml...converting from html to xhtml as a first step, and then on.

Answer (score 2):

For HTML DOM style parsing you could use Mojo::DOM

http://blogs.perl.org/users/joel_berger/2012/10/an-example-using-mojodom-for-rewriting-html.html

http://blogs.perl.org/users/tempire/2011/02/easy-dom-parsing-with-mojodom.html

[Parsing HTML with Mojolicious User Agent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13809845/parsing-html-with-mojolicious-user-agent)

1: my $dom = Mojo::DOM->new( $content );

2:

3: not needed

4:

```
#remove stylesheets
$dom->find('link')->each( sub{ $_->remove if $_->{rel} eq 'stylesheet' } );
```

5: It is possible, but it is worth a new question

6: Checkout the links

example:

```
Mojo::UserAgent->new->get('http://www.google.com/search?q=mojolicious')
->res->dom->find('h3.r a')
->each( sub { print shift->all_text . "\n" } );
```

Comment: on 5, yes, it may be worth a new question, but it is also nice to have a set of short recipe in one question.  I checked out Mojo::DOM, and it seems like an interesting alternative to XML::LibXML.  The synopsis at the start of its web page contains some nice examples.  your other links were very interesting, too.